# How ta make data-filter attribute value variable

Tags: jquery, function, variables, attributes

I want to make a funtion that can change the data-filter value to any varible
example :-
its given .Y i want to convert it to mal_item2 to filter mal elements , change to tan_item5 to filter tan elements.As mal and tan are two different variety of elemnets.Its like subfilter of two options which is mal and tan

the concept is to pass a variable in data-filter attribute value

```
<ul class=" row container-fluid filterList group" id="show">
    <button class="secondbtn btn btn-sucess  btn-lg dropdown-toggle type=" button" onmousedown="this.size=5;"
        onfocusout="this.size=1;" data-toggle="dropdown"">Select Cat</button>
        <div class=" dropdown-menu edit2" id="dropdownItem" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li class=" dropdown-item box Y filterListItem item btn "  data-filter=".Y" onclick="filter('Y')">Y</li>
        <li class=" dropdown-item box C filterListItem item btn "  data-filter=".C" onclick="filter('C')">C</li>    
        </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to show that function *you*'re making and having issues with. PS: stop using inline js and `on*` handlers. JS is supposed to be in one place, and that's inside your script tag, not dispersed inside HTML files.

Comment: Have not made any ,I want a funtion to make the value variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a data- filter attribute value variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249959/how-to-make-a-data-filter-attribute-value-variable)