# How to make a data- filter attribute value variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, filter

**I want to make the data-filter value in li class variable for more filter options**

```
    <button class="secondbtn btn btn-sucess  btn-lg dropdown-toggle type=" button" onmousedown="this.size=5;"
        onfocusout="this.size=1;" data-toggle="dropdown"  onclick="yclick()">Select Cat</button>
        <div class=" dropdown-menu edit2" id="dropdownItem" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">           
            <li class=" dropdown-item box filterListItem item btn " data-filter="Y">Y</li>
            <li class=" dropdown-item box filterListItem item btn " data-filter="C">C</li>  
        </div>



function yclick() {

    $('li.boxY:eq(0)').data('filter', 'malY');
    $('li.boxC:eq(1)').data('filter', 'malC');
    var value = $('li.boxY:eq(0)').data('filter');
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what you want and what you have tried, because honestly i have no clue what you want.

Comment: I want to make the data-filter value in  li  a variable so that i can change its value with time through a function

Comment: You want to just be able to set the `data-filter` value from code, is that right?

Comment: Yeah and I have  made the change through the given answer of this question but problem is still there ,after value is changed through function it remains same for the upcoming task which required it to be changed to perform further

Answer (score 0):

To access, or change, the `data-*` value on an element you can use the `data` method. Use just the name of the attribute without the prefix to read the value, or pass a second parameter to set the value. So in your case something like:

```
 var value = $('li.dropdown-item:eq(0)').data('filter');
```

would read the first item and

```
$('li.dropdown-item:eq(0)').data('filter','foo');
```

Would set the first item to the value "foo". The demo below will read the value of the li's when clicked and clicking the button will change them. Try clicking both items, then the button and clicking both items again.

```js
$('ul').on('click','li',function(){
   console.log($(this).data('filter'));
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('ul li:eq(0)').data('filter',"One");
    $('ul li:eq(1)').data('filter',"Two");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-filter="A">A</li>
  <li data-filter="B">B</li>
 </ul>
 
 <button>change filters</button>
```

Comment: but the value of data-filter remains same in index.html doesnt changes to foo

Comment: the code after that require data-filter to be changed but it remains same